# Is there any way to place the tab title in center if there is no icon?

Tags: maui, maui-blazor, maui-community-toolkit, .net-maui.shell, maui-android

I'm Looking to create two tabbed page without any icon. But it getting placed in bottom of the tab area [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts8sM.png)

I'm Expecting my tab title to be placed center if there is no image. Below is the code I used.

[This is the code I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aNYM.png)

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="Awakee.HomePage"
            xmlns:p="clr-namespace:Awakee.Views"
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
            android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
            BarBackgroundColor="Grey">
    <p:AddNewAwake Title="Add New" StyleClass=""/>
    <p:UpcomingAwake Title="Upcoming"/>
</TabbedPage>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the luxury to use a plugin that performs better and has many cool features, check [Sharpnado.Tabs](https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Tabs) It is the best tabs library out there for Tabs

With a TabsHostView that hosts your tab and a ViewSwitcher that switches between available views its a full pack solution

```
  <tabs:ViewSwitcher x:Name="Switcher"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       Animate="False"
                       SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedViewModelIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <customViews:LazyView x:TypeArguments="tabsLayout:HomeView" BindingContext="{Binding HomePageViewModel}" />
        <customViews:LazyView x:TypeArguments="tabsLayout:ListView" BindingContext="{Binding ListPageViewModel}" />
        <customViews:LazyView x:TypeArguments="tabsLayout:GridView" BindingContext="{Binding GridPageViewModel}" />
    </tabs:ViewSwitcher>

    <tabs:TabHostView Grid.Row="2"
                      HorizontalOptions="Center"
                      VerticalOptions="Start"
                      HeightRequest="60"
                      WidthRequest="280"
                      TabType="Fixed"
                      IsSegmented="True"
                      CornerRadius="30"
                      Margin="15"
                      BackgroundColor="#F0F0F3"  
                      Shades="{sh:NeumorphismShades}"
                      SelectedIndex="{Binding Source={x:Reference Switcher}, Path=SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <tabs:TabHostView.Tabs>
            <tabs:BottomTabItem Style="{StaticResource BottomTabStyle}"
                                IconImageSource="house_96"
                                Label="{localization:Translate Tabs_Home}" />
            <tabs:BottomTabItem Style="{StaticResource BottomTabStyle}"
                                IconImageSource="list_96"
                                Label="{localization:Translate Tabs_List}" />
            <tabs:BottomTabItem Style="{StaticResource BottomTabStyle}"
                                IconImageSource="grid_view_96"
                                Label="{localization:Translate Tabs_Grid}" />
        </tabs:TabHostView.Tabs>
    </tabs:TabHostView>
```

Checkout their Readme for more information:

https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Tabs/blob/main/README.md

On the other hand, if you want to go ahead with TabbedPage then you will have to write a handler that handles this, you can follow this for more information

[How to center Tabbed Page Tab Icons and/or text in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67129674/how-to-center-tabbed-page-tab-icons-and-or-text-in-xaml)

[Modify TabbedPage Bar with handler in .NET Maui (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74126950/modify-tabbedpage-bar-with-handler-in-net-maui-android)

Comment: Thanks. But I have added Sharpnado.Tabs.Maui  to my nugget and did mapped it with my MauiProgram.cs like this  public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
 {
     var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
     builder.UseMauiApp<App>()
         
 .UseSharpnadoTabs(loggerEnable:false);
 return builder.Build(); Also added xmlns:tabs="clr-namespace:Sharpnado.Tabs.Droid;assembly=Maui.Tabs" in my tabbed page but still getting "The type 'tabs:BottomTabItem' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built." Am I missing something?

Comment: This is the correct namespace btw     xmlns:tabs="http://sharpnado.com"

Comment: I have a feeling you have added the NuGet package incorrectly, check if your MAUI app references Sharpnado Tabs or not

Comment: https://ibb.co/Zg3r5K2 Hope this is the one

Comment: I see, Can you try creating a repro on Github i would like to check this out, because I have this control in my production app that works perfectly

Comment: This is my first time adding the maui project into git. So it has taken time and here is the repo link. I particularly created for learning this tab and the extension you recommended. https://github.com/Bolt367/trainingMaui.

Comment: This seems to fine, I cloned it and built it without issue!

Comment: But for me it is not recognizing :\

Comment: Are you able to build without this package?

Comment: Yes I did. And working fine as well\